# How to register custom hibernate type using spring boot?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

In hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#types-registry) custom types are registered using a **[Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html)** instance. How can I access this instance and register my type using spring boot?

Using **@TypeDef** for entities works fine, but with a jpa native query i get a `"javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111"`

It works with my own dialect and registering via **[registerHibernateType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#registerHibernateType-int-java.lang.String-)**, but with only one custom type registered to column type **Types.OTHER** (JDBC type 1111). Any other custom type registration overwrites old one.

The query is simple, only selects a constant value of the given custom type.

Using hibernate 5.0.9 and spring boot 1.4.0.

Comment: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/map-ms-sql-server-datetimeoffset-to-java-8-offsetdatetime/5937/7

Comment: @gavenkoa this doesn't work for multiple custom types with the same sql type. In your workaround, you had to deregister old type to prevent conflict.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems there is no automatic mapping of the result to a custom type.

For postgres, the returned jdbc [PGObject](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/util/PGobject.html) contains the column type name (ex: 'tsvector'), but the hibernate custom types knows only the sql type (OTHER in this case), not the db type name, so it cannot do the match.

The workaround is to unwrap the jpa native query and register the returned scalar type (custom hibernate type), ex:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery( "SELECT <SOMETHING> AS res" );
query.unwrap( SQLQuery.class ).addScalar( "res", CustomHibernateType.INSTANCE );
```

Note that this affects QueryDSL (4.1.4), as there is no mechanism to register the scalar as hibernate custom type, so the jpa native query fails ([JPASQLQuery](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.4/apidocs/com/querydsl/jpa/sql/JPASQLQuery.html)). The workaround in this case is to use a non-jpa native query with a [AbstractType](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.4/apidocs/com/querydsl/sql/types/AbstractType.html) registered with QueryDSL, and the conversion will be done automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue 
Postgresql driver 42.2.2 
Hibernate 5.2.17

I have fixed the issue by adding a custom SQL Dialect.

```
import java.sql.Types;
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect;

public class CustomPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQL94Dialect {

  public ConnectedWellPostgreSQLDialect() {
    super();
    registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, "pg-uuid");
  }
}
```

And configure configure hibrenate to use the new class:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.config=com.mypackage.CustomPostgreSQLDialect
```

Comment: I have already tried this as I said in my original question. The problem with this solution is that if you register another type (with Types.OTHER) it overwrites the previous one, rendering it unusable, and I have multiple custom types.